# Windows Game Development Tutorial

Tags: games

I Am New to windows phone development, I would like to develop games in windows platform, I don't have experience in developing game, Can any one provide me good link of good tutorial for learning game development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Windows phone dev center](http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us) is really the best place to start. There's a good, step by step guide to the whole process lifecycle.

Then when you have specific questions jump over to StackOverflow and research/ask questions there.

Generally there are two types of app: XAML based and XNA. XAML based apps are the types of apps with lists, text boxes and buttons. Generally displaying or capturing data. XNA apps are good for game development as you can control exactly what is rendered, but it's obviously a bit harder as you have to manage the physics etc yourself.

There are some XNA based frameworks to help get you started with game development. [Unity](http://unity3d.com/unity) is a good example.